# How to update values while user manipulates UI data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and designing a Windows form with c++ language.  I'm having trouble putting code together to update a text box value simultaneously while the user chooses their check in time in the date time picker box.  Here is my psuedocode, I'd appreciate it if you help me or point me to the right information.

```
private: System::Void dtpMondayIn_ValueChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         while (true){
             if (this->dtpMondayIn->Value++ or Value--){
                 Update->txtMonday->Text;
             }
```

Comment: That doesn't look like c++ to me.

Comment: what's this: "this->dtpMondayIn->Value++ or Value--" ...and this "Update->txtMonday->Text"???

Comment: Your pseudo-code is not correct - no cycles and no checks needed. On `dtpMondayIn_ValueChanged` you just need to make an update for your data.

Comment: That code is what I'm trying to achieve.  Right now, when I press ctrl and f5 to run the program, the text box only shows the datetimepicker default value at launch, when I change the value while running the program, the text box doesn't change parallel with the datetimepicker.